# Weird false-positive of javac data flow analysis

Tags: java, compiler-errors, static-analysis, javac, dataflow

I have code of the following form:

```
class Test {
  private final A t;

  public Test() {

    for ( ... : ... ) {
      final A u = null;
    }

    t = new A();
  }

  private class A {}
}
```

Compiler says:

```
variable t might already have been assigned
```

Interestingly, if I perform any of the following changes to the loop it works out!

- Change the loop's content to `A u = null`
- Remove the loop (but keep `final A u = null;`)
- Replace the foreach-style loop with a classic counting loop

What is going on here?

**Note:** I could not get the minimal example to cause the error so there is probably something wrong with the "environment" (about 1400 loc). I can not see what could disturb the initialisation of `t`, though, as `t` is written to nowhere else.

Fun fact: IntelliJ IDEA says "Variable 'u' can have 'final' modifier..." if I remove it.

I use javac 1.6.0_26.

**Update:** There you go, this example so *so* minimal:

```
import java.util.List;

class A {
  private final boolean a;

  public A() {
    for ( final Object o : new Object[] {} ) {
      final Object sh = null;
    }

    a = true;
  }

  class B {
    private final Object b1;
    private final Object b2;

    B() {
      b1 = null;
      b2 = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Fails to compile on `javac 1.6.0_26` but compiles on `javac 1.7.0_02`. So I guess I hit some wicked corner case of ... something?

Note that you can do any of

- Remove any one member
- Remove `final` inside the loop in `A()`
- Replace the loop with a normal `for` loop, e.g. `for ( int i=0; i<100; i++ ) { ... }`

and it will compile.

Comment: You might have custom compiler settings, which IDE are you using?

Comment: I run `mvn install`; our project does not define compiler parameter (afaik).

Comment: Seems like an IntelliJ issue to me.  Eclipse does not exhibit this problem for me.  Certainly if the loop does not reference `t` then it shouldn't impact it later.

Comment: CLI maven shows the error. I agree it should not, but it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the problem is fixed in Java 7, it is probably a bug in the Java 6 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of code I would try this.

```
private final A t;

public Test() {
    final int t = 1;

   for ( ... ) {
      final A u = null;
   }

   this.t = new A();
```

This will cause any code which "might" initialise `t` to fail (and show up in the compiler.

Comment: As I state in the question, there are no other writes to `Test#t`. I confirmed this by usage search, string search and -- just to amuse you -- by provoking compiler errors as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If you're constructor happen to call another constructor that doesn't itself set `t`, the compiler fails to understand that.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349559/java-constructor-final-variable-assignment).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually thought of that, too, but no, there is no such call. In fact, I only define this one constructor. My real class is top level and does not extend any other (but `Object`), so there should be no intereference on this front. It implements an interface but that should not hurt.

Comment: @Raphael I guess that you'd better supply an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) except that it should NOT compile of course... It compiles fine in IntelliJ.

Comment: If I knew the essential parts I would know the problem don't you think? ;) I don't see how the outside stuff can affect this, so I have no idea where to start adding/removing stuff. I am trying, though.

Comment: It took me a while, but I have a small example now. See above.

Answer (score -2):

It is my understanding that storing an object in a final var does not make your object immutable but its reference. That explain why when you remove the final keyword it works and as per removing the for-loop, i think you are accessing the object reference and not an instance.

Comment: `u` is never accessed or written to after its initialisation (in a reduced form of the real code which still fails to compile).