# Java - how to handle this "might not be initialised" error?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, error-handling

<s>Is there a feature that lets me check on which path the variable for which I'm getting a "might not be initialised" error is supposedly not initialised? Preferably either native to Java or built into Intellij?</s>

**EDIT: managed to reduce my code to a minimal failing example**

```
class MyFailure{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
        String test;
        boolean abort = false;
        while(!abort){
            if(false){
                abort = true;
                continue;
            }

            test = "stupid";
            if(test.equals("stupid")) break;
        }

        if(!abort){
            System.out.println(test);
        }
    }
}
```

> Main.java:21: error: variable test might not have been initialized

Suppose the while loop reads from a server socket until the buffered value satisfies a certain condition and the `if(false)` is in fact a check whether the client closed the connection, how would you suggest I handle this?

Comment: If you can't find the path with your eyes, your code is too complicated. Show it.

Comment: In my experience, the mechanism for deciding isn’t too smart (and probably ought not be not to complicate matters too much). For example, if I have two if-else constructs after each other in a method and I know that a certain path in the first implies a certain path in the second, Java doesn’t figure that out. So if my variable was only initialized in one path through the first, Java is not letting me use the value in any of the paths in the second.

Comment: A possible trick is to assign a nonsense-value to the variable in the declaration (like -4736 for an int). The two good effects are: Java is happy. And I’m sure to discover if the nonsense value gets used because of a programming error.

Comment: @OleV.V. Assigning a bogus value only masks the problem.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, I see your point, but I still think there are nuances to that question. If the problem is that your logically correct code doesn’t compile, assigning a bogus value does a little more than mask the problem. If the problem is that your code is too complicated that you can find the non-assigning path, the trick only makes the code more complicated, that is, worse.

Comment: @OleV.V. I've never seen this error from logically correct code.  [There may have been a bug in the Java 6 compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112927/weird-false-positive-of-javac-data-flow-analysis), but it was fixed.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, I wonder if you and I understand the same by “logically correct”. I’ve seen it more than once in Java 8.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede please see edit for a simplified version of the code I'm dealing with.

Comment: @OleV.V. Guess you were right about the bogus. Want to elaborate so I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code in your question there is a fairly straightforward solution: use the variable inside the loop where Java too can see it has a value:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
    boolean abort = false;
    while (!abort){
        if (false) {
            abort = true;
            continue;
        }

        String test = "stupid";
        if (test.equals("stupid")) {
            System.out.println(test);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Whether this will work in your real-life code I cannot tell. Consider extracting a method for dealing with the value obtained from the socket and call it from where the `System.out.println()` is in the example.

Edit: For what it’s worth, the following version compiles too. You may still think that the use of the value (the `println`) is so deeply nested it reduces readability:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    if (! isFalse()) {
        String test;
        do {
            test = "stupid";
        } while (! isFalse() && ! test.equals("stupid"));
        if (! isFalse()) { // connection still open, so not aborted
            System.out.println(test);
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isFalse() {
    return false;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments I do sometimes — hesitatingly — resort to initializing the variable in question with a nonsensical/bogus value in the declaration so that if that value ever gets used because of a programming error, I will discover. In your example I might use `null`:

```
String test = null;
```

And after the loop:

```
assert test != null;
```

so I will catch if it didn’t get a proper value. It’s not a solution I’m happy with, but it happens that I cannot find anything better.

Comment: Maybe not the most readable solution considering the ``println`` in my example is a dummy for much more complicated code and may - for example and depending on the value received - have to request more data from the socket. (Also, the problem occured within one such huge while you're proposing so I'd have a huge while within a huge while just for the sake of telling Java that the variable is, in fact, initialised.)

Comment: I’m still thinking if you put that much more complicated code in a separate method, you may end up with something manageable. I haven’t seen your code, though, so don’t take my word for it.

Comment: You know ... I just noticed that if I set ``String test = null`` and then test for ``null``, intellij will warn me that >``test != null`` is always true. But if I remove the ``= null`` I get the "might not be initialised" error ... so I'm working with a program that CAN tell I'm assigning to the string and at the same time it can't .... weird.

Comment: @User1291, IntelliJ is sometimes smarter than Java itself, which can give rise to such clashes.